# Drawing two graphs in one canvas properly with ROOT

Tags: root-framework

I'm trying to plot to graphs in one canvas using Cern ROOT. When I use `gr -> Draw("ap")` and `gr2 -> Draw("p1 same")`, the lines of the plots are not visible, only the markers are visible. When I use `gr1 -> Draw("")` and `gr2 -> Draw("same")`, the first plot is visible with line and marker but the second plot is only visible with line and not markers.

I want to see both of their lines and markers. How can I do it? My code:

```
graph_one -> GetXaxis() -> SetTitle(" x ");
graph_one -> GetYaxis() -> SetTitle(" y ");
graph_one -> GetXaxis() -> SetRangeUser(0,8);
graph_one -> GetYaxis() -> SetRangeUser (0,3);
graph_one -> SetLineWidth(2);
graph_one -> SetLineColor(kBlack);
graph_one -> SetMarkerStyle(8);
graph_one -> SetMarkerSize(3);
graph_one -> SetMarkerColor(kRed);

graph_two -> SetLineWidth(2);
graph_two -> SetMarkerStyle(8);
graph_two -> SetMarkerSize(3);
graph_two -> SetLineColor(kBlue);
graph_two -> SetMarkerColor(kBlack);

graph_one -> Draw("");
graph_two -> Draw("same");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    graph_one -> Draw("acp");
    graph_two -> Draw("cp");
```

- `a` draws the axes around the graph (obviously needed only for one graph)
- `c` draws a continuous line between the markers
- `p` draws the markers themselves

(this is explained in https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTGraphPainter.html#GrP1)

[image: superimposed graphs]

Please note there is no `same` drawing option for `TGraph`.